# Insert Rich Text Editor in theme?

Tags: theme-development, tinymce

I'm building a custom front end form for my theme and I'd like to use the Wordpress TinyMCE Rich Text Editor for it. Is there an easy way to invoke it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('tiny_mce');
```

This will include the TinyMCE javascript. Then simply use TinyMCE as you wish

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",
});
</script>
```

You could also opt to use a Wordpress plugin for TinyMCE, such as this [TinyMCE plugin for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/), which is very popular.